# Specify maxiter in Diffeqr Package

Tags: r, julia, ode, differential-equations

I am trying to solve a system of ODEs using the `Diffeqr` package in R ([link](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/diffeqr/index.html) to documentation). When solving the system an error occurs, stating: "*Larger maxiters is needed*."

**Example**:

```
library(diffeqr)
library(plotly)

diffeq_setup()

### Adapted Zombie apocalypse model (Munz, 2009) ###

# Drift function
f <- function(u,p,t) {
  du1 = u[4] * u[1] - p[1] * u[1] * u[3] + p[2] * u[2]
  du2 = p[1] * u[1] * u[3] - p[2] * u[2] - p[3] * u[2]
  du3 = 100 + p[3] * u[2] - p[1] * u[1] * u[3] + p[2] * u[2]
  du4 = 0
  return(c(du1,du2, du3, du4))
}

# Diffusion function (note that noise terms are 0)
g <- function(u,p,t) {
  return(c(0*u[1], 0*u[2], 0*u[3], 0*u[4]))
}

u0 = c(100000, 0, 0, 0.7)            # initial conditions
tspan <- list(0.0,1000)              # timespan to solve over
p = c(0.0002, 0.005, 0.02)           # parameter values
sol = diffeqr::sde.solve(f,g,u0,tspan,p=p,saveat=1, abstol = 10^(-3))
udf = as.data.frame(sol$u)

plot_ly(udf, x = sol$t, y = ~V1, name = 'Zombies', type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines') %>%
  add_trace(y = ~V2, name = 'Zombie/human conflicts', mode = 'lines') %>%
  add_trace(y = ~V3, name = 'Zombies', mode = 'lines')
```

The error that occurs is as follows:

```
> sol = diffeqr::sde.solve(f,g,u0,tspan,p=p,saveat=1, abstol = 10^(-3))
┌ Warning: Interrupted. Larger maxiters is needed.
└ @ DiffEqBase ~/.julia/packages/DiffEqBase/cp0Wf/src/integrator_interface.jl:150
```

I tried to specify `maxiter` in the `sde.solve()`, however, it was not possible to add a `maxiter` argument to that.

**Question**
How do you manually set the `maxiter` to a higher value?

Comment: There is no way to pass options other than the tolerances to the julia-lang library. It is that DifferentialEquations.jl that produces the errror message. Try using the `saveat` option to pass an array of sampling locations, perhaps the counter bounded by `maxiters` is restarted for each sub-interval, thus increasing the total iteration bound. Python's odeint (lsode) works that way.

Comment: I just added it to the package right now. If you `devtools::install_github('JuliaDiffEq/diffeqr', build_vignettes=T)` to get the master branch then you can use the `maxiters=...` argument. If that works for you, we can submit this update to CRAN.

Comment: Question: do you know if your problem is stiff (in the ODE sense)?

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses and your help! @ChrisRackauckas: I am currently testing, if it works. I think the ODEs are stiff...

Comment: If it's stiff, the adaptive SDE solver may still be able to handle it, albeit with a lot of iterations. We need to build out more stiff solvers. The current crop of standard methods like implicit methods don't do well. I plan to get SROCK methods in here over the summer.

Comment: @ChrisRackauckas It seems to work:)! Great, thanks! However, for large timespans the simulations take up quite some time (even with the JIT compiled functions). Does a larger value for `saveat` (e.g. `saveat = 1`) influence the outcome/precision or speed? Or an increased `abstol`? Any suggestion is welcome;)!

Comment: This is stiffness. This method is not efficient on this equation, but methods for stiff SDEs is difficult. I haven't found the traditional stiff SDE methods (implicit Euler-Maryuama et. al) much more efficient than what's the default here. But we will be adding more methods to improve solving this kind of equation in the near future.

Comment: @ChrisRackauckas I noticed that an update of the DiffEqr package in R was available, great! I tried to use the SROCK1 and SROCKEM methods in the example above, as `sde.solve(..., alg = "SROCK1()")`, however, I get an error: `Error: Error happens in Julia. UndefVarError: SROCK1 not defined`. Do you know, what happens here? Thanks again for such a great package!

Comment: The StochasticDiffEq packages this uses may need an update. Those SROCK methods are brand new. You might need to go into your Julia and manually `]up`